# setting a variable equal to the current selected option

Tags: javascript, html

javascript:

```js
function read() {
  var x =  document.getElementById("selectedcust").options[document.getElementById("selectedcust").selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(x);
}
```

html:

```html
<select  id="selectedcust"  style="position: absolute; top:-8px;left: 80px;" onchange="read()">
```

Basically I want the variable `x` equal to the current selected option. However as it stands whenever you change the selected item the variable does not change.

EDIT: for anyone who is also trying to do this note that my above code does work. The problem lay elsewhere.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5sz0j308/

Comment: problem is that this problem is part of a very big class,multiple classes in fact. So no I dont think so sorry

Comment: Works as expected here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/YXMGGX?editors=101

Comment: Your above code is working for almost all of us. If you could share a fiddle reproducing your problem, we would be able to help.

Comment: I think my problem must be related to something else so I'm going to look at the rest of my code now that I know this isn't the problem but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion based on what Sachin Kadam has, You could greatly shorten that one statement by passing "this".

```
 <select  id="selectedcust"  style="position: absolute; top:8px;left: 80px;" onchange="read(this)">
     <option>aaaaaaa</option>
     <option>bbbbbbb</option>
     <option>ccccccc</option>
     <option>ddddddd</option>
     <option>eeeeeee</option>
 </select>
<script>
         function read(e) {
            var x =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
             console.log(x);
            }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5oLrwkxm/1/

Comment: thank you for your help. I think the problem lies elsewhere but thank you for helping me clean up my code I am quite new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I think there is some script reference error.
As its throwing error as read function is not define. you need to include script before `</body>` tag.

```
<body>
 <select  id="selectedcust"  style="position: absolute; top:8px;left: 80px;" onchange="read()">
     <option>aaaaaaa</option>
     <option>bbbbbbb</option>
     <option>ccccccc</option>
     <option>ddddddd</option>
     <option>eeeeeee</option>
 </select>
<script>
         function read() {
            var x =  document.getElementById("selectedcust").options[document.getElementById("selectedcust").selectedIndex].value;
             console.log(x);
            }
</script> 
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5oLrwkxm/

Comment: Hi could you clarify your comment a bit please I don't see any difference between my code and yours

Comment: yes, there is no difference. I just changed location of <script> tag and moved it to bottom of page, just before closing <body> tag. Its working. i used jsfiddle just to run the code.

Comment: hm okay I think the problem may lie somewhere else in my code which I will fix by myself but thank you for helping me eliminate this as the possible cause.